# How to color a single Dojo button?

Tags: html, css, dojo

Is there a way to affect a single Dojo button's color? I want to be able to override the default button color for specific buttons.  In the JSP markup I have a button defined like so:

```html
<button class="jelam-button-blue" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" data-dojo-id="usdotSearchButton" id="usdotSearchButton" type="button" onClick="csfController.usdotSearch()">Search</button>
```

where the "jelam-button-blue" is defined in our css file like so:

```css
.jelam-button-blue {
    background-color: #5494c7 !important;
    background-image: none !important;
    border: 1px solid #a6cdec !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    color: #ffffff !important;
    height: 38px;
}
.jelam-button-blue .dijitReset.dijitInline.dijitButtonText {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    position: relative;
    top: 2px;
}
```

This does not result in the button turning blue as I would like.  The markup that gets generated from the button markup is:

```html
<span role="presentation" class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dijitButton" widgetid="usdotSearchButton">
  <span role="presentation" data-dojo-attach-event="ondijitclick:__onClick" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonNode">
    <span aria-labelledby="usdotSearchButton_label" role="button" data-dojo-attach-point="titleNode,focusNode" class="dijitReset dijitStretch dijitButtonContents" tabindex="0" id="usdotSearchButton" style="-moz-user-select: none;">
      <span data-dojo-attach-point="iconNode" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitIcon dijitNoIcon"></span>
      <span class="dijitReset dijitToggleButtonIconChar">●</span>
      <span data-dojo-attach-point="containerNode" id="usdotSearchButton_label" class="dijitReset dijitInline dijitButtonText">Search</span>
    </span>
  </span>
  <input type="button" data-dojo-attach-point="valueNode" role="presentation" tabindex="-1" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" class="dijitOffScreen" value="">
</span>
```

and the generated markup doesn't include any reference to the "jelam-button-blue" class that I had specified.

I'm including the dojo module from my local theme, defining the dojoConfig variable before I include the dojo.js like so:

```js
<script>
var dojoConfig = {
    baseUrl: "/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/",
    async: false, // to support older pre-AMD IBM modules
    tlmSiblingOfDojo: false,  
    packages: [
        { name: "gridx", location: "dojo/gridx-1.3.0" },
        { name: "dojo",  location: "dojo/1.9.1/dojo" },
        { name: "dijit", location: "dojo/1.9.1/dijit" },
        { name: "dojox", location: "dojo/1.9.1/dojox" },
        { name: "commonjs", location: "js" }
    ]
};
</script>
<script src="/CompassThemesURS/themes/html/commonurs/dojo/1.9.1/dojo/dojo.js.uncompressed.js"
               data-dojo-config="isDebug:true, parseOnLoad: false"></script>
```

Is there a way to turn just the designated button a specified color?
Thanks.

Comment: Hey there okorng, can you provide a bit more of your code? Did you require dijit ? ( I mean how did you added the dojo library? from the google hosted library or locally? )

Comment: I updated the question to show that I am requiring the dojo modules from my local source, not the Google CDN.  Thanks.

Comment: I did run a sample code, with your details, and the button is blue...no markups like you have there.. ( did you try to create the button programmatically? )

Comment: I haven't tried programmatically.  I need it to work with markup.  I'll try to recreate it on jsfiddle.

Comment: Here's a jsfiddle example.  http://jsfiddle.net/gregorco/eyLewa1n/1/  It initially shows it as blue, but then tops it with a non-blue color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update the dijitButtonNode color.

I Changed your css to:

```
.jelam-button-blue .dijitButtonNode {
background-color: #5494c7 !important;
background-image: none !important;
border: 1px solid #a6cdec !important;
border-radius: 0 !important;
color: #ffffff !important;
```

}

http://jsfiddle.net/theinnkeeper/eyLewa1n/2/